# JSON.parse giving me object instead of result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have variable in javascript which is coming from php by json_encode.
While I am psrsing it with JSON.parse(variable). It alert me objects instead of actual result.

CODE:

```
var a = '<?php echo json_encode($over_branch_array); ?>';
a = JSON.parse(a);
alert(a);
```

EDIT:

basically I need to map my php array.

```
a = a.map(function(v){
    return { id : v.branch, text : v.branch };
});
```

If I will do JSON.stringify then I won't be able to do that..

Comment: The result should be an object ... what are you expecting?  Change `alert` to `console.log` and check the console instead.

Comment: BTW, you don't need your quotes. Hence, you don't need json.parse

Comment: In JavaScript, arrays are objects.

Comment: If your json string is `{....}`, then you ARE going to get an object. you'd only get an array if the string was `[...]`

Comment: if you want to display the contents of an object / array then JSON.stringify() it.

Comment: view my edit please..

Comment: Putting quotes around that in the definition makes a JSON string, not a JSON object. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

`alert` performs a `toString` conversion on objects before displaying them. You'll get a result like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/22ahM/).

If you want to view the contents of the object, either `console.log` it or `JSON.stringify` it.

EDIT:

When I say use `JSON.stringify` I mean do it to show what is actually in the object:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(a));
```